# how to simulate cloth dragging on collision surface in blender 2.8

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am new to blender (in fact, I am new to the whole 3D rendering), I was watching a tutorial on youtube ([[2.8] Blender Tutorial: Cloth Animation in EEVEE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7TdEzRwgzs)) on how to simulate a cloth and tried following along. everything worked out fine as  I followed along. 
the animation is something like this:
1- cloth is initially hovering as a plane in the z-axis
2- it will start to fall and collide with a plane
3- pin groups are moving along the x-axix
4- cloth is colliding with a bowl

however, when I watched the rendered images, I noticed that there is a crease/wrinkle that is formed when the cloth falls to the plane and that crease/wrinkle remain unchanged as the cloth is dragged on the surface.
[image]

how can I smooth out the crease/wrinkle as the cloth getting dragged?
I tried adding stickiness and friction on the plane but it remained the same.